# MassTransit Saga : Some event was missing to transition the stage

Tags: c#, masstransit

I am developing transaction order that SAGA State can be switch between acknowledged or pendingAcknowledged. I found that sometime if I submit with more than 10 ReplaceOrderAcknowledge events. There is a chance that one or two of
SAGA state not be moved to "Acknowledged" per expect. While task MarkReplaceOrderAcknowledged was called and completed. But the state is not moving. or sometime event ReplaceOrderAcknowledge  was not consumed and make my SAGA state keep always be "PendingAcknowledged".

I am using MassTransit 6.3.1.  Any suggestion on this mssing?

```
    Initially(
        When(AlgoRequested)
                .ThenAsync(SendMarketDataSubscriberAsync)
                .TransitionTo(MarketDataSubscribed),
        During(MarketDataSubscribed,
            Ignore(AlgoRequested),
            When(MarketDataChanged)
                .Then(MarketDataChangedTask)
                .TransitionTo(PendingAcknowledged));

        During(Acknowledged,
            When(MarketDataChanged)
                .Then(MarketDataChangedTask)
            When(MarketDataChanged, ShouldGrab)
                .ThenAsync(HandleGrabAsync)
                .TransitionTo(PendingAcknowledged),
           When(MarketDataChanged, ExceedTickAwayPrice)
                .ThenAsync(ExceedTickAwayPriceAsync)
            When(MarketDataChanged, ShouldFloatNotGrab)
                .ThenAsync(HandleFloatAsync)
                .TransitionTo(PendingAcknowledged),
            When(MarketDataChanged, context => context.Instance.CancelSubmitted)
                .ThenAsync(HandleCancelRequestAsync))

        During(PendingAcknowledged,
            Ignore(AlgoRequested),
            Ignore(MarketDataChanged),
            When(FloatAwaken)
                .Then(FloatAwakenTask)
                .Then(context => Log.Information("{@AwakenDoNothing}", context.Instance)),
           
           
            When(ReplaceOrderAcknowledge)
                .ThenAsync(MarkReplaceOrderAcknowledge)
                .Then(context => Log.Information("{@ReplaceOrderAcknowledge}", context.Instance))
                .ThenAsync(SendMarketDataRequestedAsync)
                .TransitionTo(Acknowledged),
            ,
```

Adding function MarkReplaceOrderAcknowledge

```
private async Task MarkReplaceOrderAcknowledge(BehaviorContext<FGOrderDetailState, IAlgoReplaceAcknowledged> context)
    {
        if (context.Data.OrderDetail.MsgSequenceNumber > context.Instance.AlgoMsgSequenceNumber)
        {
              context.Instance.MarketDataUsed = false;

            var algoAck = context.Data;
            algoAck.CorrelationId = context.Instance.OriginalCorrelationId;
            await _strategyBus.Publish<IAlgoReplaceAcknowledged>(algoAck);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No way to know given the code shown, sorry. State machines works, I'd suggest additional logging to understand the flow of messages/state through the state machine.

Comment: Adding MarkReplaceOrderAcknowledge,  I suspect that "await _strategyBus.Publish<IAlgoReplaceAcknowledged>(algoAck);"  is the root cause.

Comment: well, that should be `context.CreateConsumeContext().Publish`, also make sure the interface is public.